# link a "recipe" package in homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, package, homebrew

I am trying to install a specific version of a "recipe" (graphviz-2.29.20121209.0545.pkg in OSX 10.8) to aid in data visualization for RoR, but after installing the developer version since the stable release isnt ready yet, I used the installer.   I wanted to make sure homebrew knew of it, so I typed `brew install graphviz` and got `graphviz-2.28.0 already installed, it's just not linked`.  I am wondering how to link it?

[package url](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should just have to do:

```
brew link graphviz
```

Hope this helps!